# JavaFX Error: Don't know how to detect os family "primarystages"

Tags: java, javafx

Everytime I try to run a javafx file. This error occurs. It is not limited to a single java file but all the fx files give this same error. I suppose it has something to do with NetBeans settings.

[Screenshot of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGctq.png)

Comment: Please don't post errors/code as images.

Comment: Also please provide relevant code snippets (primarily your .fxml file)